# python read CSV with commas as separators but interpret commas inside quotes as thousands

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am tried to read in data from a govt. website using:

`df = pd.read_csv("https://ir.eia.gov/wpsr/table9.csv",encoding = 'unicode_escape', error_bad_lines=False,thousands=',')`

but for some reason it doesn't parse correctly and still returns strings. Should it be converting to float/int or do I need an additional step/would it be better to utilize `.replace(',','')` for the columns in question?

### Sample from csv file

```
"STUB_1","STUB_2","12/25/20","12/18/20","12/27/19","12/28/18","12/25/20","12/27/19"
"Refiner and Blender Net Production ","Finished Motor Gasoline (excl. Adjustment)","9,051","8,726","9,942","9,637","8,718","10,007"
"Refiner and Blender Net Production ","East Coast (PADD 1)","2,821","2,787","3,148","3,069","2,749","3,193"
"Refiner and Blender Net Production ","Midwest (PADD 2)","2,323","2,249","2,480","2,399","2,257","2,545"
"Refiner and Blender Net Production ","Gulf Coast (PADD 3)","2,259","2,145","2,504","2,418","2,143","2,455"
"Refiner and Blender Net Production ","Rocky Mountain (PADD 4)","311","268","304","297","280","310"
"Refiner and Blender Net Production ","West Coast (PADD 5)","1,337","1,277","1,506","1,455","1,289","1,504"
"Refiner and Blender Net Production ","Adjustment","140","103","230","-104","2","2"
"Refiner and Blender Net Production ","Reformulated","2,738","2,684","3,123","3,054","2,660","3,156"
"Refiner and Blender Net Production ","East Coast (PADD 1)","1,064","1,063","1,296","1,237","1,042","1,288"
"Stocks (Million Barrels) ","Lower Atlantic (PADD 1C)","0.469","0.431","0.379","0.556","– –","– –"
"Stocks (Million Barrels) ","Midwest (PADD 2)","0.331","0.201","0.463","0.422","– –","– –"
"Stocks (Million Barrels) ","Gulf Coast (PADD 3)","0.941","1.064","2.541","1.296","– –","– –"
"Stocks (Million Barrels) ","Rocky Mountain (PADD 4)","0.143","0.138","0.165","0.182","– –","– –"
"Stocks (Million Barrels) ","West Coast (PADD 5)","0.259","0.250","0.255","0.226","– –","– –"
"Stocks (Million Barrels) ","> 500 ppm sulfur","7.865","7.289","11.047","10.550","– –","– –"
"Stocks (Million Barrels) ","East Coast (PADD 1)","2.929","2.962","4.021","4.628","– –","– –"
"Stocks (Million Barrels) ","New England (PADD 1A)","0.335","0.338","0.574","0.595","– –","– –"
"Stocks (Million Barrels) ","Central Atlantic (PADD 1B)","1.806","1.896","2.936","3.222","– –","– –"
"Stocks (Million Barrels) ","Lower Atlantic (PADD 1C)","0.788","0.728","0.512","0.811","– –","– –"
"Product Supplied ","Finished Motor Gasoline","8,128","8,022","8,961","8,623","7,931","9,139"
"Product Supplied ","Kerosene-Type Jet Fuel","1,217","1,196","1,972","1,631","1,218","1,787"
"Product Supplied ","Distillate Fuel Oil","3,594","4,174","3,055","3,203","3,790","3,780"
"Product Supplied ","Residual Fuel Oil","275","128","292","454","190","263"
"Product Supplied ","Propane/Propylene","1,755","1,292","1,318","1,623","1,602","1,415"
"Product Supplied ","Other Oils","4,348","4,278","4,356","3,560","4,338","3,987"
"Ultra Low Sulfur Distillate Reclassification ","< 15 ppm Distillate, Downgraded to 15 to 500 ppm","–","–","–","–","–","–"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- A value in a dataframe with a comma (e.g. `2,238`) is not interpreted as a numeric value. The `thousands` parameter in `pandas.read_csv()` allows numeric columns with `,` to correctly be converted to a numeric dtype where the `,` is the thousands separator, instead of a decimal point.
- There is an issue with the data, which is preventing the columns from being converted to numeric data types.

  - `"Stocks (Million Barrels) ","Lower Atlantic (PADD 1C)","1.728","1.758","1.128","1.319","– –","– –"`

    - `"– –"` is actually `'\x96 \x96'`
  - `"Ultra Low Sulfur Distillate Reclassification ","< 15 ppm Distillate, Downgraded to 15 to 500 ppm","–","–","–","–","–","–"`

    - `"–"` is actually `'\x96'`

```py
import pandas as pd

# read the csv from the web site
df = pd.read_csv("https://ir.eia.gov/wpsr/table9.csv", encoding='unicode_escape', error_bad_lines=False)

# replace the problem characters in all columns
df = df.replace('\x96 \x96', '0').replace('\x96', '0')

# replace the , in the numeric columns and convert to float
df.iloc[:, -6:] = df.iloc[:, -6:].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',', '').astype(float))

# sum the columns as test
df.iloc[:, -6:].sum()

[out]:
12/25/20      337124.121
12/18/20      332599.398
12/27/19      371574.469
12/28/18      366347.128
12/25/20.1    325203.600
12/27/19.1    365255.800
dtype: float64
```

### Alternatively

```py
import pandas as pd

# read the file
df = pd.read_csv("https://ir.eia.gov/wpsr/table9.csv", encoding='unicode_escape', error_bad_lines=False)

# replace to problem characters
df = df.replace('\x96 \x96', '0').replace('\x96', '0')

# save the file
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)

# read the file back in
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', thousands=',')

# print(df.info())
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 538 entries, 0 to 537
Data columns (total 8 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------      --------------  -----  
 0   STUB_1      538 non-null    object 
 1   STUB_2      538 non-null    object 
 2   12/25/20    538 non-null    float64
 3   12/18/20    538 non-null    float64
 4   12/27/19    538 non-null    float64
 5   12/28/18    538 non-null    float64
 6   12/25/20.1  538 non-null    float64
 7   12/27/19.1  538 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(6), object(2)
memory usage: 33.8+ KB
```

Comment: Ah thank you, I had it backwards. I thought thousands would work over string columns for some reason